# Mysql query WHERE Json value = this

Tags: php, mysql, json, joomla

I need to write a mysql query within a xml field. Joomla provides me the format and its relatively simple for most things. Except can I actually write a query that checks a json value within  the attribs column.

Below is just my example, I know it won't work. But that's what I want to do.

```
SELECT * 
FROM com_content 
WHERE atrribs(form_show) = 1
```

also below is the json format that the attribs column is holding

```
{

"form_show":"1",
"form_avilable":"0",
"mycategory":"4",
"response":"Thank you!",
"forms":{

"fieldinstruction":["blah","blah"],
"fieldmanditory":["0","0"]

}

}
```

Note: Here is the format joomla explains.
Taken from joomla docs

docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type

```
<field 
    name="myfield" 
    type="sql" 
    default="10" 
    label="Select an article" 
    query="SELECT id, title FROM #__content" 
    key_field="id" 
    value_field="title" 
/>
```

You can also assemble or calculate fields in the SQL statement. For example, suppose you wanted to append the created date/time of each article to the article title in the list. Then you could use this SQL statement:

```
SELECT id, concat( title, ' (', created, ')') AS title 
FROM #__content
```

What I need to do is write a mysql query using the above format but it needs to get a value from within one column and its also a json.

Thanks to anyone in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, which is precisely the reason storing JSON strings in a DB should be approached with caution.  That being said, none of the example columns you used are stored in JSON in Joomla's content table.  Are those the actual values you were looking for?

Your only option is to parse the returned result set in PHP to do any further filtering.  Depending on your end goal you might be able to insert PHP logic into your MVC path model or table class to handle any filtering.  Are you writing a custom component or implementing a layout override?

Comment: @Brian_Bolli I'm confused by you saying that attrib is not stored in JSON.  It is is the images field, the url field, and the metadata field.

Comment: @Brian_Bolli thanks im looking at your comments now.

Comment: @Brian_Bolli It goes into the attribs column via a plugin called alter articles. A very simple plugin i was able to add to a form tab within the article. I now want to retrieve a value from that json.

Comment: @jonnypixel OK, sorry for the delay, just got to home office. :)  It sounds like you want to include the param column as a SELECT and then use the native PHP function json_decode to translate the JSON string into a PHP object.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Elin I was riding the bus home when I posted and only saw the last query example and assumed, in my error, the SELECT's where the columns he was after.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to query

```
$mystring = '%'.'"form_show":"1"' . '%';
$query->where($db->quoteName('attrib')   .' LIKE '. $db->quote($mystring) );
```

(fixed this)